# chapters in videos for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, video

Is it possible to use chapters in videos for the iPhone in an application?

For example:
I have a 3 minutes video to play. I have chapter 1 starting at 0s, chapter 2 at 50s, chapter 3 at 95s.

Can I start plating the video at 50s (chapter 2) until the end? Can I make it play just the chapter 2 from 50s to 95s?

My question is not about how to add chapters to a video. I want to know if this behaviour is available on the iphone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iPhone SDK 3.0+ has a new MPMoviePlayerController.initialPlaybackTime property for setting the time to start movie playback.  This will be "rounded" to the nearest earlier keyframe time, so does not provide exact start positioning, but pretty close.

Comment: the problem is, not all videos have a lot keyframes. This function can cause accuracy problems when the keyframe time is far away from required time.

Answer (score 2):

player.currentPlaybackTime = time;

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible sending the non-documented message **setCurrentTime** to MPMoviePlayerController. It takes one parameter of type double which specifies the playback position in seconds. Find below a short example:

Extend the MPMoviePlayerController to avoid compiler warnings:

```
@interface MPMoviePlayerController (extended)
-(void)setCurrentTime:(double)seconds;
@end
```

Then you can call it wherever you need it - before start or during playback.

```
MPMoviePlayerController* player = [[ MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url ];
[ player setCurrentTime:95.0 ];
[ player play ];
```

Comment: Apple started rejecting apps that use unpublished APIs. And even if your app is accepted, it may break after any OS update. Do _not_ use unpublished APIs like this in App Store applications, however compelling it may be.